# DataLoader Causing RAM Crashes in PyTorch Federated Learning: Solutions?

Tags: pytorch-dataloader, federated-learning

I'm trying to implement federated learning to forecast solar photovoltaic generation using the LADPU dataset.
After preprocessing the dataset, I partitioned it into segments to simulate a federated environment, aligning each segment with unique `METER_FID` values for 10 different clients.
The next step involved creating sequences from these partitions as LSTM model inputs.
I used a `create_sequence` function for this, targeting sequences with `START_READ` and `END_READ` features to predict `INTERVAL_READ`.
However, when I split these into training and validation sets and set up PyTorch `DataLoader` objects (including a separate `test_loader` for evaluation), there is an issue. My Colab session consistently crashes due to exhausting all available RAM.
I tried to reduce the batch size and limit to 6 CSV files,but the issue persists.

I am very new to it,I am referring to the tutorials and documentation given in https://flower.ai for my usecase.I can't figure out the problem or possibly I am missing out on something. Can anyone please help.

```
#for partitioning I did this

 NUM_CLIENTS = 10

def partition_data(df, num_clients):
    np.random.seed(42) 
    unique_ids = df['METER_FID'].unique()
    np.random.shuffle(unique_ids) 
    partitions = np.array_split(unique_ids, num_clients)  
    partitioned_dfs = [df[df['METER_FID'].isin(ids)] for ids in partitions]
    return partitioned_dfs

partitioned_dfs = partition_data(df, NUM_CLIENTS)

#then created sequences from each partition to serve as input for an LSTM model
def create_sequences_efficiently(df, sequence_length=5):
    sequences, targets = [], []

    df = df.sort_values('INTERVAL_TIME')
    for i in range(sequence_length, len(df)):
        sequence = df[['START_READ', 'END_READ']].values[i-sequence_length:i]  
        target = df['INTERVAL_READ'].values[i]  
        sequences.append(sequence)
        targets.append(target)
    return np.array(sequences), np.array(targets)

#then split
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, TensorDataset
import torch
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


def create_loaders(partition, sequence_length=5, batch_size=32):
    sequences, targets = create_sequences_efficiently(partition, sequence_length)
    # Convert sequences and targets into PyTorch tensors
    sequence_tensor = torch.tensor(sequences, dtype=torch.float32)
    target_tensor = torch.tensor(targets, dtype=torch.float32)
    # Create a TensorDataset and DataLoader
    dataset = TensorDataset(sequence_tensor, target_tensor)
    return DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

# create the loaders for each partition
train_loaders, val_loaders = [], []
for partition_df in partitioned_dfs:
    # Split the data of each client into training and validation sets
    train_df, val_df = train_test_split(partition_df, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
    # Create loaders for the training and validation sets
    train_loader = create_loaders(train_df, sequence_length=5, batch_size=16)
    val_loader = create_loaders(val_df, sequence_length=5, batch_size=16)
    train_loaders.append(train_loader)
    val_loaders.append(val_loader)
```